# Paradox regarding non-normalizable wavefunctions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, normalization

Suppose that we have a quantum particle with defined momentum $p=\hbar k$, this means that the particle is in an eigenstates of the momentum operator $|k \rangle$. We can now ask: what is the wavefunction $\langle x | k \rangle =\psi _k(x)$ of this particle? It turns out that this is:
$$\psi _k(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{ikx} \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$
Wonderful. Now that we have the wavefunction we can ask another question: what is the probability of finding the particle in the range of positions $(x_1,x_2)$? We know that when a particle is in a **generic state** $|\psi\rangle$ with wavefunction $\langle x |\psi\rangle=\psi(x)$ the probability of finding it between $x_1,x_2$ ($P_\psi(x_1,x_2)$) is:
$$P_\psi(x_1,x_2)=\int_{x_1}^{x_2} |\psi(x)|^2dx$$
So this same structure should apply to our particle in the state $|k\rangle$ since the rule mentioned above is valid for any generic state. So the probability of finding the particle in state $|k\rangle$ between $x_1,x_2$ should be:
$$P_k(x_1,x_2)=\int _{x_1}^{x_2} |\psi _k(x)|^2dx$$
**But:** Since we are dealing with a particle in an eigenstate of momentum, so with defined momentum, we can invoke Heisenberg's Principle that allow us to state the following:

> A particle with determined momentum has completely undetermined position.

From this we can deduce that, for a particle in the eigenstate $|k\rangle$, the probability of finding it in a position interval **should be spread out along all the real line**, in other words: **every position interval should be equiprobable**; but of course the probability of finding it somewhere should be $1$ so we can see that **the probability of finding the particle in any finite interval $(x_1,x_2)$ should be zero**.[1]

So, from Heisenberg's Principle, we have proven that we should get:
$$P_k(x_1,x_2)=\int _{x_1}^{x_2} |\psi_k(x)|^2dx=0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$$
But by carrying out the calculations, from equation $(1)$, we instead get:
$$P_k(x_1,x_2)=\int _{x_1}^{x_2} |\psi_k(x)|^2dx=\int _{x_1}^{x_2} \psi^*_k(x)\psi_k(x)dx=\int _{x_1}^{x_2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-ikx}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{ikx}dx=\frac{x_2-x_1}{2\pi} \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$$
This is a clear contradiction! Why do we get $P_k(x_1,x_2)=(x_2-x_1)/2\pi$ and not $0$ as we expected?

The most common answer I hear is: The wavefunction is simply not normalizable! But what does it mean to be not normalizable from a physical point of view? **What meaning is carried by the wavefunction $\psi _k(x)$ if it is not linked to a probability in this case?** And what about what we have proven using Heisenberg's Principle? Why the wave function doesn't simply return zero when it should? Is it not a contradiction?

---

[1]: Of course in the real world we can't have a particle with perfectly determined momentum, but we can get close, and by the upper reasoning we should expect the probability of finding the particle in a generic interval $(x_1,x_2)$ to become smaller and smaller as the value of momentum becomes more and more determined.

Comment: The probability is $P=\dfrac{\int_{x_1}^{x_2}|\psi|^2}{ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|\psi|^2}$, not what you wrote. I invite you to evaluate the correct integral.

Comment: Can you expand on why the probability is what you have written? I always tought that my formula was correct, this confuses me a lot.. My formula is even reported on wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_function#Normalization_condition)..

Comment: @Noumeno. Well, wikipedia is what it is, an encyclopedia in which subjects (especially in scence) could be incorrectly or incompletely treated, therefore it is not a valid reference. One usually takes textbooks and articles in peer-reviwed journals as valid quoting sources.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Also all my textbooks report the formula i have written

Comment: @DanielC Also all my textbooks agree with my formula..

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I mean, now that I think about this: the formula you have written is compatible with mine in the case of a normalizable function, the denominator becomes one, and on the other hand it would kinda solve my apparent paradox on the normalization, since the denominator diverges. Cool stuff, but I don't know how to prve your formula unfortunately.. where does it came from? How do you derive it? If you could expand on this it would be very helpful on top of very interesting!

Comment: @Noumeno If you assume the probability density function is proportional to $|\psi(x)|^2$ (which is an axiom of quantum mechanics), then the **only** possible normalization is the one that AccidentalFourierTransform wrote down. This just follows from properties of probability density functions; eg see the wikipedia page on [normalizing constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalizing_constant).

Comment: Also I just want to point out that my answer and AccidentalFourierTransform's comment are both making the same point.

Answer (score 3):

Your formula for the probability to find the particle the interval $[x_1,x_2]$,
\begin{equation}
P(x_1,x_2) = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} {\rm d} x |\psi(x)|^2
\end{equation}
is only valid if $\psi(x)$ is normalized so that the integral of $|\psi(x)|^2$ over all space is equal to $1$. Since, as you have pointed out, the momentum space eigenfunction is not normalizable, this condition is not satisfied by the momentum eigenfunctions, and your formula for the probability does not apply.

Comment: Yes, but this answer is the most common one that I cited in my question: The wavefunction is not normalizable so the integral simply isn't a probability. Ok. But the question I am interested about, as I pointed out, is: what physical meaning is carried by the wavefunction if it is not linked to a probability anymore?

Comment: @Noumeno It means you can't interpret the square of the momentum eigenfunction as being a valid probability density. Now the failure to be a true probability distribution is in some sense "mild," and are some situations where you can get away with treating the momentum eigenstate as if it was a pdf (eg if you want to compute the average momentum). But really if you want to be rigorous, you can only compute probabilities if you use "wavepackets" (normalizable superpositions of position/momentum eigenstates).

Comment: Having said that, position and momentum eigenstates are extremely useful for performing calculations, even if at the end to compute a probability you need to use a wavepacket.

Comment: @Noumeno, the wave functions for exact momentum and position states have no physical meaning because they are not physically realisable states. These states can be given mathematical meaning as distributions, and they are useful for calculations, but do not think they should have any physical meaning.

Comment: @CharlesFrancis I don't want to derail this comment thread, but I think it's too strong to say that "the wave functions for exact momentum and position states have no physical meaning." I think it's fair to say that we could never determine that the true state of Nature will never be exactly in one of these states. But there is a very useful interpretation of these states as being the results of idealized, perfect position and momentum measurements.

Comment: @Andrew, I think that does derail this thread. To me it is quite clear  that "idealized, perfect position and momentum measurements" are not physical. This in no way detracts from the value of using such states in calculation, and distribution theory allows us to do so at least in typical calculations in non-relativistic quantum mechanics. Distribution theory breaks down in quantum field theory, but that is a whole other can of worms.

Comment: I'll agree to disagree :)

Answer (score 2):

Your formula is not valid for states of exact position and momentum precisely because they are not physical states. They have no physical meaning and are not states in Hilbert space, precisely because the inner product is not defined as a function.

The formula given by  @AccidentalFourierTransform in comments comes directly by applying the Born rule, which is covered in any sensible textbook. Clearly this only applies to normalisable states, and is equivalent to normalising the state.

In non-relativistic quantum mechanics, you can either just get on with an intuitive understanding that momentum and position "states" are not states in Hilbert space, and are not physical, but that using them as though they were states works for practical purposes, or you can study distribution theory.

Answer (score 0):

Any vector of a finite (or at least countable) dimension is expressed as a linear combination of its basis vectors:
$\mathbf V = \sum a^k\mathbf e_k $

In this case it is possible to choose a set of $a^k$ so that, for a given $n$, $a^k = 1$ if $k = n$ and zero otherwise. So, one of the possibilities of the vector is to be one of the basis vectors. Or to be one of the eigenvectors, if the basis is the set of eigenvectors of some operator.

But a wavefunction belongs to a space of infinite and uncountable dimension. It is expressed as:

$\psi(x) = A\int \tilde{\psi}(k) e^{ikx}dk  $

By that definition, it is not possible for a wavefunction to be an K-eigenfunction $e^{iKx}$, for some K, if it is required that $\tilde{\psi}(k)$ is continuous.

Unless it is allowed that $\tilde{\psi}(k) = \delta(k-K)$. But the Dirac delta is not properly a function.

Comment: Why should $\tilde\psi$ be required to be continuous?

Answer (score 0):

> The most common answer I hear is: The wavefunction is simply not normalizable! But what does it mean to be not normalizable from a physical point of view? What meaning is carried by the wavefunction ψk(x) if it is not linked to a probability in this case?

It means such a function is not a valid wave function for the purposes of finding probability that the particle is in specified region of configuration space using the Born formula

$$
P = \int_{region} |\psi|^2 dx.
$$

The exponential function
$$
f_k(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{ikx}~~~(*)
$$
is a so-called plane wave normalized to delta function. This means that

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_k f_k' dx = \delta(k-k')
$$
which is useful in calculations.

Such function is non-zero in all infinite space, so it isn't L2 normalizable and the Born interpretation does not apply to it. You can also see it does not even have the correct units to give probability. The function has the attractive property

$$
-i\hbar \frac{\partial f_k}{\partial x} = \hbar k f_k(x)~~~(**)
$$

which sometimes makes people say this is "eigenstate of momentum operator $\hat{p}_x$ with eigenvalue $\hbar k$." But this is a sloppy thinking; yes, it obeys the equation (**), but that's it - it does not belong in the Hilbert space. Hilbert space has only normalizable functions, which implies we can interpret them using the Born rule.

Sometimes we want to use infinite plane wave as an approximation to the actual correct wave in some limited region of space. This is possible if we choose such a plane wave (with correct pre-factor) that its value matches the real wave in the region of interest, say, volume $\Delta V$. The fact that the plane wave is non-physical when considered in all space may be ignored.

A different approach is to never use delta-normalized plane wave, but instead put the system in a big imaginary box of volume $V$ and use normalized plane waves

$$
g_k(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{V}}e^{ikx}.
$$

These are in Hilbert space and allow Born's interpretation. But the box is kind of artificial so it is important to make sure results don't depend on $V$.

A lot of calculations in standard quantum theory are done instead with plane waves normalized to delta function (*) and it is assumed that the result is correct. Thus it is generally assumed the same result would be obtained even using only normalized functions in place of $\psi$, either localized packets or normalized plane waves. But doing so is more complicated a involves proving the result does not depend on the shape of the packets or $V$, so most authors take the easy route and use (*).